# How to add Publisher Certificate to Cx_freeze msi bundle?

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze, publisher, ms-publisher

I'm trying to make an " msi " using cx_freeze. When I distribute it to users, it's showing unknown publisher.

How to get publisher certificates, How can I add it to cx_freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to purchase a certificate from a certified vendor, like Verisign or Thawte. The certificate must be a code signing Microsoft Authenticode certificate.

Sign your binaries and the MSI with this certificate and your users will now see your company info in the UAC prompt from now on.

**EDIT** To sign the files you can use [SignTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: how to sign my binaries?

Comment: What I understand is, I need to sign binaries. But using python and cx_freeze it directly produces msi bundle. Can I add cert to msi bundle directly ?

Comment: Yes, you can and you must sign the MSI too. That is the part that helps you get rid of the "Unknown publisher" message. I just recommended to also sign the binaries because its better to see that those are provided by you, for example for antiviruses.

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided. Can I get certs for free?

Comment: I'm afraid not (from what I know), all valid certificates are generated by companies that do this for a business (so they need to get money somehow :)). However, I recommend you research the offers very well, as the prices can vary quite a lot. [P.S. don't forget to mark the question as answered]

Comment: This still doesn't quite answer the question though. In order to build a msi file with cx_Freeze you must run: `python setup.py bdist_msi`. This builds both the binary .exe, and then the .msi, but as far as I can tell there are no ways to hook into the `bdist_msi` command to codesign the .exe before it builds the .msi.